# Using curl in specific directory via SSH?

Tags: curl, ssh

I would like to download a file via Curl. I however do not have the entire URL, I am however connected via SSH to the directory with the file. How does one do this?

Comment: Must it be via curl? If you are connected to the file location w/ ssh, why not just use scp?

Comment: @Politank-Z I've only used Curl, but if there is any other approach I'm open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using scp, it stands for secore copy. You can use the same credentials as for you ssh login plus the path to the file.

```
scp username@host:folder/file.bsp /local/folder
```